# How do I create the json for creating a distributed Kafka Connect Instance with a transformation?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Using standalone mode I create a connector and my customized transformation like that:

```
name=rabbitmq-source
connector.class=com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
rabbitmq.host=rabbitmq-server
rabbitmq.queue=answers
kafka.topic=net.gutefrage.answers
transforms=extractFields
transforms.extractFields.type=net.gutefrage.connector.transforms.ExtractFields$Value
transforms.extractFields.fields=body,envelope.routingKey
transforms.extractFields.structName=net.gutefrage.events
```

But for a distributed connector what is the syntax for the PUT request to the Connect REST API? I cannot find any example in the docs.

Already tried a couple of things like:

```
cat <<EOF >/tmp/connector
{
  "name": "rabbitmq-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "rabbitmq.host": "rabbitmq-server",
    "rabbitmq.queue": "answers",
    "kafka.topic": "net.gutefrage.answers",
    "transforms": "extractFields",
    "transforms.extractFields": {
      "type": "net.gutefrage.connector.transforms.ExtractFields$Value",
      "fields": "body,envelope.routingKey",
      "structName": "net.gutefrage.events"
    }
  }
}
EOF

curl -vs --stderr - -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @/tmp/connector "http://localhost:8083/connectors"
rm /tmp/connector
```

or also this did not work:

```
{
  "name": "rabbitmq-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "rabbitmq.host": "rabbitmq-server",
    "rabbitmq.queue": "answers",
    "kafka.topic": "net.gutefrage.answers",
    "transforms": "extractFields",
    "transforms.extractFields.type": "net.gutefrage.connector.transforms.ExtractFields$Value",
    "transforms.extractFields.fields": "body,envelope.routingKey",
    "transforms.extractFields.structName": "net.gutefrage.events"
  }
}
```

For the last variant I get the following error:

```
{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nInvalid value class net.gutefrage.connector.transforms.ExtractFields for configuration transforms.extractFields.type: Error getting config definition from Transformation: null\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}
```

Please note that with the properties format it works nicely (using Landoops Create New Connector UI in fast-data-dev. Interesting that the Landoop's Ui feature 'translate to curl' produces the very same json as my second example)

**Update**

To be sure that it's not a problem with Landoop, docker and with my custom transformation, I've started zookeeper, broker, schema registry and Kafka Connect in distributed mode with the standard distributed properties from COP 3.3.0

`bin/connect-distributed etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties`

which logs 

`[2017-09-13 14:07:52,930] INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/connectors/confluent-oss-gf-assembly-1.0.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:176)
[2017-09-13 14:07:53,711] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/opt/connectors/confluent-oss-gf-assembly-1.0.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:199)
[2017-09-13 14:07:53,711] INFO Added plugin 'com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:132)
[2017-09-13 14:07:53,712] INFO Added plugin 'net.gutefrage.connector.transforms.ExtractFields$Key' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:132)
[2017-09-13 14:07:53,712] INFO Added plugin 'net.gutefrage.connector.transforms.ExtractFields$Value' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:132)`

All good so far. Then I created a connector config:

`cat <<EOF >/tmp/connector

{
  "name": "rabbitmq-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "rabbitmq.host": "rabbitmq-server",
    "rabbitmq.queue": "answers",
    "kafka.topic": "net.gutefrage.answers",
    "transforms": "extractFields",
    "transforms.extractFields.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value",
    "transforms.extractFields.field": "body"
  }
}
EOF`

Please note that there I do now use the standard (bundled) extract field transform.
When I post that with `curl -vs --stderr - -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @/tmp/connector "http://localhost:8083/connectors"`

I get the same

`` {"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nInvalid value class org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField for configuration transforms.extractFields.type: Error getting config definition from Transformation: null\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}* ``

Comment: "did not work" --> did you get an error? What was the error?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Added the error message for the second example, which I think should be the working one. Also double checked with your blog and second variant looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the $Value in transforms.extractFields.type=net.gutefrage.connector.transforms.ExtractFields$Value is not interpreted as a variable by the bash command cat. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the Kafka Connect worker in *standalone* mode, then you must start the worker and supply the worker configuration file *and* one or more connector configuration files. All of those configuration files are in Java properties format, so the first configuration sample you provided is the correct format:

```
name=rabbitmq-source
connect.class=com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
rabbitmq.host=rabbitmq-server
rabbitmq.queue=answers
kafka.topic=net.gutefrage.answers
transforms=extractFields
transforms.extractFields.type=net.gutefrage.connector.transforms.ExtractFields$Value
transforms.extractFields.fields=body,envelope.routingKey
transforms.extractFields.structName=net.gutefrage.events
```

If you want to run the Kafka Connect worker in *distributed* mode, then you will have to first start the distributed worker and then create the connector as a second step using [the REST API](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/restapi.html#connectors) and a `PUT` request with a JSON document to the `/connectors` endpoint. That JSON document would match the format of you're second JSON document:

```
{
  "name": "rabbitmq-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "rabbitmq.host": "rabbitmq-server",
    "rabbitmq.queue": "answers",
    "kafka.topic": "net.gutefrage.answers",
    "transforms": "extractFields",
    "transforms.extractFields.type": "net.gutefrage.connector.transforms.ExtractFields$Value",
    "transforms.extractFields.fields": "body,envelope.routingKey",
    "transforms.extractFields.structName": "net.gutefrage.events"
  }
}
```

The Confluent CLI, included in Confluent's Open Source Platform that includes Kafka, is a developer tool to help you quickly get started by running a Zookeeper instance, a Kafka broker, the Confluent Schema Registry, the REST proxy, and a Connect worker in distributed mode. When you load a connector, you specify the connector configuration as either a JSON file or property file, converting the latter to a JSON format using `jq`.

However, the error you reported is:

```
{
  "error_code":400,
  "message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nInvalid value class net.gutefrage.connector.transforms.ExtractFields for configuration transforms.extractFields.type: Error getting config definition from Transformation: null\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"
}
```

The important part of this error message is "Error getting config definition from Transformation: null". Although this is a bit too cryptic, it means that the `config()` method of the `net.gutefrage.connector.transforms.ExtractFields` Java class is returning null.

Make sure that the `net.gutefrage.connector.transforms.ExtractFields$Value`string you specified is the correct fully qualified name for the nested static class `Value`, and that the `Value` class fully and correctly implements the `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Transformation<? extends ConnectRecord<R>>` interface. Note that the `config()` method must return a non-null `ConfigDef` object.

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/ExtractField.java#L97) of a Single Message Transform (SMT) that ships with Apache Kafka, or [Robin's blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/) for other examples.

Comment: Thanks for your long answer. My question wasn't very specific in this but for the JSON connector format I am using the distributed mode. I made an clarification in the text. 
Secondly, you mention PUT, but it has to be a POST with Landoop.
Third, you overlooked that my custom transform already works in the properties format, both in standalone mode or with the CLI in distributed mode on the worker itself. So I would argue that my Custom Transformation is valid?

Comment: Here you can have a look: https://gist.github.com/breadfan/10aa3baeea15fd577b3bfac2f1494e2d . I know it isn't complete since it only allows traversal into structs, but this is work in progress...

Comment: Interesting enough I do get the same error with a standard 
{
  "name": "rabbitmq-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "rabbitmq.host": "rabbitmq-server",
    "rabbitmq.queue": "answers",
    "kafka.topic": "net.gutefrage.answers",
    "transforms": "extractFields",
    "transforms.extractFields.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value",
    "transforms.extractFields.field": "body"
  }
}

Comment: Please see also my update where I started everthing locally on my machine without using docker, Landoop or a custom transformation

Answer (score 0):

For using json format of connector config and the CP connect CLI, the jq tool has to be installed on the machine where the Kafka-Connect Cluster is running.

E.g. for Landoops fast-data-dev environment you'll have to

```
docker exec rabbitmqconnect_fast-data-dev_1 apk add --no-cache jq
```

Then this will work:

```
docker exec rabbitmqconnect_fast-data-dev_1 /opt/confluent-3.3.0/bin/confluent config rabbitmq-source -d /tmp/connector-config.json
```

This doesn't solve the issue when using the connector REST endpoint though.

Answer (score 0):

With `fast-data-dev` you can build a JAR file for any connector, and then just add it in the classpath with the instructions at

https://github.com/Landoop/fast-data-dev#enable-additional-connectors

The UI will auto-detect the new connector - and provide you instructions when you hit NEW for the new connector at:

http://localhost:3030/kafka-connect-ui

What would also be worth trying - as `fast-data-dev` comes already with an generic MQTT sink connector, is trying it out. See instructions at http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/mqtt-sink.html

You would effectively need to do
`connect.mqtt.kcql=INSERT INTO /answers SELECT body FROM net.gutefrage.answers`

As this is a generic MQTT connector - possibly you will need to add the rabbitmq client library using the `enable-additional-connectors` instructions

Comment: Thanks, but this has only little to do with the essence of my question: the problems with configuring transformations for connectors in distributed mode